# How to convert "2011-04-29 00:00:00" to "29-Apr-2011" in python Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe :

```
    col_1             col_2   ... col_n
2011-04-29 00:00:00   data1   ... data_n
```

Need it to be

```
col_1         col_2  ... col_n
29-Apr-2011   data1  ... data_n
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pd.to_datetime()` for converting your date columns to datetime dtype and `strftime()`to customize format according to your need so here you need format `"%d-%b-%Y"`:

```
df['col_1']=pd.to_datetime(df['col_1']).dt.strftime("%d-%b-%Y")
```

OR

For more columns use `agg()`/`apply()` following the same code:

```
df=df.agg(lambda x:pd.to_datetime(x).dt.strftime("%d-%b-%Y"))
```